# How does Restlet client handle media type of request?

Tags: java, json, http-headers, restlet

I've got several newbie questions about how Restlet client handles media type header:

1. What will Restlet client put in 'content-type' header if I pass in an entity of type a) a POJO or b) an InputStream instance? And what the 'accept' header will be?
2. If I want to transfer a POJO in JSON format in HTTP body, do I need to serialize the POJO and pass it in as a JSON string or can I just pass in the POJO and Restlet will do the rest? If it's the former case, do I need to specify the 'content-type' header and how?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rely on the ClientResource class, you can add a MediaType parameter to your put call, such as

```
put(myPojo, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

**UPDATE**
Actually, the extra media type parameter defines the accepted result type expected from the remote resource, but doesn't apply to the sent entity.

The control on the media type of the entity/POJO sent is based on the ConverterService default settings, which depends on the extensions available on your classpath and their respective order.

You can have full control by directly invoking the

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://targetDomain/path");
cr.put(cr.toRepresentation(myPojo, new Variant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

You also need to add the org.restlet.ext.jackson extension on your classpath and its dependencies. The XStream extension is another option.

Comment: So with MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON as the second param, myPojo will get serialized to json string automatically? Is this done by restlet extension?

Comment: Sorry, my initial response was incorrect, see the update above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves my problem. With a further reading on api docs, I'm passing in JacksonRepresentation entity directly, but not sure if this is discouraged.

Comment: @JeromeLouvel Related to this question/answer, can you help me with this issue we are facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207489/use-json-xml-serialization-with-gwt-clientproxy-instead-of-gwt-serialization