# Send PUT, DELETE HTTP request in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, web-services, http-post, httpurlconnection, http-delete

I have created web service call using java below code. Now I need to make delete and put operations to be perform.

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/questions");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(jsonBody.getBytes());
os.flush();
```

When I add below code to perform DELETE action it gives errors saying:

> java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output.

```
conn.setRequestMethod( "DELETE" );
```

So how to perform delete and put requests?

Comment: Please excuse the shouting, but **WHAT** errors does it give? Also, I would suggest [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) from apache.

Comment: edited the question. Any sample codes for web service requests? Any help?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection help?

Comment: I will checked this but it does not worked for me some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PUT` example using `HttpURLConnection`:

```
URL url = null;
try {
   url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/putservice");
} catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
try {
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.write("hello");
} catch (IOException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}  finally {
    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
        try {
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (httpsURLConnection != null) {
        httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

`DELETE` example using `HttpURLConnection`:

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/deleteservice");
} catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
try {
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
    System.out.println(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
} catch (IOException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally {         
    if (httpURLConnection != null) {
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: In delete I need to use httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); is it posssible?

Comment: java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output

Comment: This example was the first Delete i found that works!

Answer (score 3):

FOR PUT

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
    httpCon.getOutputStream());
out.write("Resource content");
out.close();
httpCon.getInputStream();
```

FOR DELETE

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestProperty(
    "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
httpCon.connect();
```

Actually got it from the link here:
[Send PUT, DELETE HTTP request in HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923658/send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you to use restlet client for  web service request .please refer the bellow sample code ,it may help you

```
 Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTP);
   clientResource = new ClientResource(url);
        ResponseRepresentation responseRep = null;
         try {
            clientResource.setNext(client);           
            clientResource.delete();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();

       }
```

Comment: How to set content-type and the content? What is different HttpUrlConnection and this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630094/how-does-restlet-client-handle-media-type-of-request  please refer this link for content type handling

Comment: let me check this link. Thanks for help.