# Android using HttpUrlConnection library, method not setted to PUT

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm using HttpUrlConnection and I would like to change the request method to `put`, this is the code:

```
uri = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(60000); //60 secs
        con.setReadTimeout(60000); //60 secs
        //con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "Your Encoding");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authCode);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod(type);
```

but when i debug the project, the method is `GET` what must I do so i can set it to `PUT`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051004/how-to-send-put-delete-http-request-in-httpurlconnection

Comment: did you try this answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/26926110/3678308 ??

Comment: it's the same code !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/putservice");
    } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    try {
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.write("hello");
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }  finally {
        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (httpsURLConnection != null) {
            httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u for this answer, but as u see, ur code for setting request method is the same as mine ! that's my problem !