# Calling RESTful WS via restlet API

Tags: java, web-services, restlet

I'm trying to call a WS from my client code (based on Restlet) but I'm getting a bad request exception (HTTP status code 400) on the client.post method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/MPosBEService"+BeServicePath.MERCHANT_REGISTRATION;
    //String serviceUrl = "http://192.168.101.124:8081/be"+BeServicePath.MERCHANT_REGISTRATION;
    ClientResource client = new ClientResource( serviceUrl );

    addHeaders( client );

    objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

    try{
        Form form = new Form();
        form.set("username", "intendanet");
        form.set("password", "1111");

        client.post( form, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );//**this line is the culprit**

        //client.post(new  MerchantRegisterRequestPojo("intendanet","1111"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );

    }catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw e;
    }

    Response response = client.getResponse();

    if( response.getStatus().getCode() == 200 )
    {
        m = deserializeJson( (HttpEntity)response.getEntity(), MerchantPojo.class );
        System.out.println("Result:" + m.id);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ response.getStatus().getCode());

        throw new HttpStatusException(response.getStatus().getCode());
    }
}

static private void addHeaders(ClientResource client){

    client.getRequestAttributes().put(BeServiceHTTPHeader.REQ_MPOS_BE_SERVICE_LANGUAGE_ID.toString(), "1"+"");
    client.getRequestAttributes().put(BeServiceHTTPHeader.REQ_MPOS_BE_SERVICE_DEVICE_APP_VERSION.toString(), "1"+"");
    client.getRequestAttributes().put(BeServiceHTTPHeader.REQ_MPOS_BE_SERVICE_DEVICE_GENERATED_ID.toString(), "flskdjf9ksmflskmfl");
    client.getRequestAttributes().put(BeServiceHTTPHeader.REQ_MPOS_BE_SERVICE_DEVICE_INFO.toString(), "ovo je moj device!");

}

static private <T> T deserializeJson(HttpEntity json, Class<T> targetType) throws Exception{
    return objectMapper.readValue(EntityUtils.toString(json), targetType);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Tell us more about the server. What kind of request does it expect?

Comment: What is the content of `BeServicePath.MERCHANT_REGISTRATION` maybe you miss a `/`?

Comment: The server is Tomcat running either on 192.168.101.124 (remote server) or localhost. I've tried both urls but I'm getting the same exception.It expects to recieve an application/x-www-form-urlencoded mime type.

Comment: BeServicePath.MERCHANT_REGISTRATION is defined as /merchant/register so I think the url is fine.

Comment: But your request mime type is application/json, why don't you try this:
    `client.post( form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);`

Comment: @FrAn The second argument to the post method refers to the response mime type , which in my case is application/json.

Comment: Ahh you are right, sorry. The commented out line didn't work either,with `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630094/how-does-restlet-client-handle-media-type-of-request) if not already.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly what your REST service expects but I see two potential problems in your code.

First, the headers aren't correctly set in your response. You should update your method `addHeaders` as described below:

```
static private void addHeaders(ClientResource client){
    Series<Header> headers = (Series<Header>) cr.getRequestAttributes().get(
                                     "org.restlet.http.headers");
    if (headers==null) {
        headers = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
        cr.getRequestAttributes().put(
                "org.restlet.http.headers", headers);
    }

    headers.set(BeServiceHTTPHeader.REQ_MPOS_BE_SERVICE_LANGUAGE_ID.toString(), "1");
    headers.put(BeServiceHTTPHeader.REQ_MPOS_BE_SERVICE_DEVICE_APP_VERSION.toString(), "1");
    headers.put(BeServiceHTTPHeader.REQ_MPOS_BE_SERVICE_DEVICE_GENERATED_ID.to String(), "flskdjf9ksmflskmfl");
    headers.put(BeServiceHTTPHeader.REQ_MPOS_BE_SERVICE_DEVICE_INFO.toString(), "ovo je moj device!");
}
```

Secondly, you need to be careful of the content you send and the associated media type. You should have something like that:

```
// With form
Form form = new Form();
form.set("username", "intendanet");
form.set("password", "1111");

client.post(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

// With JSON
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject
jsonObj.put("username", "intendanet");
jsonObj.put("password", "1111");
client.post(new JsonRepresentation(jsonObj));
```

Hope it helps,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it still doesn't work. First, I had to use  MediaType.APPLICATION_WWW_FORM (MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED can't compile ). Second, the Restlet docs says that the second parameter to the post method denotes the response mime type, not the request type and my response mime should be application/json and request application/www-form. With the edits you made I'm getting a http 500 exception (though this exception is mapped from an NPE in org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:517)

Comment: Thanks for additional hints about your problem! Could we give me the version of Restlet you use? So I'll be able to made more tests to reproduce your problem ;-)

Comment: Thierry, thanks for all your help. Now, on localhost, I'm getting a 204 status(no content) so the headers are fine now. I rewrote the whole code using org.apache.http API and it works ok. I get a json response as expected. I'll do some more testing with the restlet code when I find the time.

Comment: Pleased to hear that! You're right for the second parameter of the method `post`... It actually corresponds to the content of the header `Accept` and specify the expected format for response.